# Mysql duplicate foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

When I try to import a database I get this error

```
SQL query:
ALTER TABLE `bid`
ADD CONSTRAINT `bid_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`auction_contact_id`) REFERENCES `auction_contact` (`auction_contact_id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `bid_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`car_id`)

MySQL said: Documentation
#1826 - Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'projekt_classics/bid_ibfk_3'
```

Looking at all the foreign keys I get this as a result

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

result

```
def     projekt_classics    bid_ibfk_2      projekt_classics    bid     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    bid_ibfk_3      projekt_classics    bid     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_ibfk_1      projekt_classics    car     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_ibfk_3      projekt_classics    car     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_ibfk_4      projekt_classics    car     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_brand_ibfk_1    projekt_classics    car_brand   FOREIGN KEY
```

searching into the sql the `bid_ibfk_3` constraint shows only 1 time.
All the data is in the imported database but I wonder how I can avoid this error.

**EDIT:**
First dropping all the tables runs the query without problems.
I export my database using PHPmyadmin.
I guess the error was because of the foreign key constraint not yet deleted before trying to create it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the result of your query, the foreign key `bid_ibfk_3` **already exists**. In fact it is in the second row of the result.

```
def     projekt_classics    bid_ibfk_2      projekt_classics    bid     FOREIGN KEY
--the row below is the foreign key that you are trying to create
def     projekt_classics    bid_ibfk_3      projekt_classics    bid     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_ibfk_1      projekt_classics    car     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_ibfk_3      projekt_classics    car     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_ibfk_4      projekt_classics    car     FOREIGN KEY
def     projekt_classics    car_brand_ibfk_1    projekt_classics    car_brand   FOREIGN KEY
```

That's why you are getting the duplicate foreign key constraint name when you are trying to execute this:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT `bid_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`car_id`)
```

You can modify your query to check first if the foreign key that you are trying to create does not exist, before actually creating it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
                   WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
                         AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
                         AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'bid_ibfk_3') THEN
   ALTER TABLE `bid` ADD CONSTRAINT `bid_ibfk_3`
        FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `car` (`car_id`);
END IF
```

Comment: Or, just remove the optional keyword `CONSTRAINT` and the symbol/identifer following it, and just `ADD FOREIGN KEY ...` since InnoDB will automatically generate unique symbols for each. (+1)

Comment: The answer is really informative, though some keywords can be removed .upvoted!