# Error executing DDL "alter table orders_wine_list add constraint FKas0ewroa6urvffgjnu25f5jv0 foreign key (order_id) references orders (id)" via

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I have a problem with that.
I was working with the perfume project
https://github.com/merikbest/OnlineShop
and wanted to convert it to wine, but I got this error
I do not understand what my mistake is, I have reviewed many articles and found nothing.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table orders_wine_list add constraint FKas0ewroa6urvffgjnu25f5jv0 foreign key (order_id) references orders (id)" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table usr_wine_list add constraint FK3sqekriy3xfd3ctdfcsumx3v1 foreign key (user_id) references usr (id)" via JDBC Statement
```

This is SQL code:

table orders

```
CREATE TABLE `wine`.`orders` (
                                  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                  `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                  `city` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                  `date` DATETIME NULL,
                                  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                  `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                  `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                  `phone_number` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                  `post_index` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
                                  `total_price` FLOAT NULL,
                                  `user_id` INT NULL,
                                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

table wine

```
CREATE TABLE `wine`.`wine` (
                                   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                   `country` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `filename` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `decantation` VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
                                   `combination` VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
                                   `grape` VARCHAR(255) NULL,      
                                   `color` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `wine_title` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `brand` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `price` INT NOT NULL,
                                   `type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `volume` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                                   `year` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

table user

```
CREATE TABLE `wine`.`usr` (
                               `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                               `activation_code` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                               `active` TINYINT NOT NULL,
                               `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                               `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                               `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                               PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

table user role

```
CREATE TABLE `wine`.`user_role` (
                                     `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
                                     `roles` VARCHAR(255) NULL);
```

table orders_wine_list

```
CREATE TABLE `wine`.`orders_wine_list` (
                                               `order_id` INT NOT NULL,
                                               `wine_list_id` INT NOT NULL,
                                               `wine_list_order` INT NOT NULL,
                                               PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`, `wine_list_order`));
```

table usr_wine_list

```
CREATE TABLE `wine`.`usr_wine_list` (
                                            `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
                                            `wine_list_id` INT NOT NULL);
```

and ALTER TABLE

```
ALTER TABLE `wine`.`orders`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK7ncuqw9n77odylknbo8aikc9w`
        FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
            REFERENCES `wine`.`usr` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


ALTER TABLE `wine`.`orders_wine_list`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FKi6hpa14qaenek8pc9pf3vmlei`
        FOREIGN KEY (`wine_list_id`)
            REFERENCES `wine`.`wine` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `wine`.`orders_wine_list`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK8jft4d30d5dgvauht7ssndwau`
        FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`)
            REFERENCES `wine`.`orders` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


ALTER TABLE `wine`.`user_role`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FKfpm8swft53ulq2hl11yplpr5`
        FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
            REFERENCES `wine`.`usr` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


ALTER TABLE `wine`.`usr_wine_list`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK1n7n8prjoexkp1twc9f6kgbtm`
        FOREIGN KEY (`wine_list_id`)
            REFERENCES `wine`.`wine` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


ALTER TABLE `wine`.`usr_wine_list`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FKc5b4lo20noteewtlrq1kd8nhs`
        FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
            REFERENCES `wine`.`usr` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Did you create the perfume database before attempting to convert to wine? If so and it's still there then mysql may be complaining about duplicate constraint names. The constraint names in your code look like they could have been generated by mysql. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501899/mysql-duplicate-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake. I just didn't change the name of the database in the proprietary file)

Answer (score 0):

just verified all the scripts under mysql env. Seems no issue.

see:  [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3jC8PGeZZEuty3XVq8gdzz/6)